# Xcode 5 asset catalog: What is "Default" image set

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

My asset catalog contains an image set `Default`:

[image]

Can I delete this image set?

Where does it come from? (I have migrated my artwork from a previous Xcode version into Xcode 5 asset catalog).

What kind of image do I need to provide for this placeholder?

My app is iPad only and targets iOS 7 only (no previous versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default.png is your splash image. You can find it in project settings. You have to replace it with your splash image in order to be approved when you upload to appstore.

[image]

Comment: I have set my launch Images in the image set `LaunchImage`, iPad portrait and landscape, retina and non-retina. Why do I need to set a splash screen for the iPhone when my app is iPad only?

Comment: If you develop iPad app, you can remove splash screens for iPhone (Default, Default@2x & Default-568@2x).