# Why UITableView is different on simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I'm new to iOS development and i was wondering why when i launch the simulator to see my Table View it creates vertical scroll but i can't see any scroll inside my Table View on story board.

[image: what i see on xcode]

[image: what i see on simulator]

[image: what i see on simulator]

Why it's happening?

Should i force the width and height for each device ( i.e: iphone 4, iphone 5, iphone 6 )? Do you know if has an 'automatic' option that scale my for each iphone or should create a new app for iphone4, another for iphone 5 and another one for ipad?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must include your all default screens for iphone/ ipad, Please follow all steps to include launch image [Managing Launch Images with Xcode](https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/unleash-your-inner-app-developer-managing-images-xcode-5-asset-catalogs)  and your launch image sizes are

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Where i include it? My problem is with Views not with images.

Comment: you have to include default.png and default2x@.png into your project..for spash screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544222/xcode-5-asset-catalog-what-is-default-image-set

Comment: It doesn't work...still creating a scroll and i can't see any scroll on interface designer ( storyboard )

Answer (score 2):

1. UITableView is subclass of UIScrollView, hence it inherits all properties of scrollviews.
2. Yes, you will have to set the frame size of the TableView for each phone size in your code. To know more about Views, View sizes and frames etc., you can refer to any common programming guide available online. (I personally recommend [Ray Wenderlich](http://raywenderlich.com)).
3. No, you don't need to build separate apps for each platform. You just need to manage views for them.